# Get horizontal heading from device orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation, device-orientation, heading

I want to use the device orientation event to check the heading of the mobile device.
This is what I do:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, false);
}
else{
    alert("Device Orientation is not available");
}
```

In my handleOrientation function I can have alpha, beta, gamma. But I want to have the heading of the device. When you lay down your device and do something like this:

[image]

```
function handleOrientation(orientData) {

    //var absolute = orientData.absolute;
    //var alpha = orientData.alpha;
    //var beta = orientData.beta;
    //var gamma = orientData.gamma;
}
```

How can I get the heading of the device from the values above?

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window.orientation, but pay attention: different devices returns different values.

```
function handleOrientation() {

    switch(window.orientation)
    case 0:
     // do your stuff
     break;
    case -90
       ....
}

window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', handleOrientation);
```

The iPhone has: ( from https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMWindowAdditionsReference/DOMWindowAdditions/DOMWindowAdditions.html )

0   => Portrait orientation. This is the default value.

-90 => Landscape orientation with the screen turned clockwise.

90  => Landscape orientation with the screen turned counterclockwise.

180 => Portrait orientation with the screen turned upside down. This value is currently not supported on iPhone.